# Execute a Swift script in terminal

Tags: swift, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I have built a command line tool, at some point, I need to execute a `curl` command. I'm creating the script that should be executed, but I don't know how.

I'm able to create the script and printing it out, but I'm not being able to execute it.
It looks something like: `curl https://api.github.com/zen`

Please ask me anything if it's not clear. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do have to 'POST' any data?

Comment: Nope, all the data are requested as a raw content and will be showing up in the CLI @mat

Comment: I question the use of `curl` here. You'll probably have an easier time with `NSURLRequest`

Comment: If I ran the `curl https://api.github.com/zen` command in terminal, it will be executed. To execute the same command, should I use `NSURLRequest `? @Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a Terminal command from Swift using `NSTask` (now called `Process` in Swift 3): If you need output, add `let output = handle.readDataToEndOfFile()` at the end. Here's the whole thing wrapped in a function (the launchPath would be `/usr/bin/curl`):

```
func runTask(launchPath: String, flags: [String]) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments = flags
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    let handle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    task.launch()
    return String(data: handle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
}
```

In your case though, you might want to have a look at `URLSession` and `URLRequest` (superseding `NSURLRequest`). To create a request to your URL and credentials, you would simply do:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url:URL(string: "https://api.github.com/zen")!)
    request.setValue("application/vnd.github.v3.raw", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("token USERTOKEN", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as String? else {
            print("Unable to format output data")
            return
        }
        print(output)
    }).resume()
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar for the help. In the runTask func, what should I pass to the launchPath? And regarding the URLSession, if I have a command with many flags, how should I done that? Example: `curl -H 'Authorization: token USERTOKEN’ -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPO/contents/PATH` @Oskar

Comment: Actually I'm not really sure what to pass to the url in `var request = MutableURLRequest(URL:url)`, here what I did in main.swift: https://gist.github.com/MEnnabah/18ecf3fbd95ecee1466d08dab896fcc4 but it's not working.

Comment: And where to pass the URL in the first method? @Oskar

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the custom request with headers. It should be ready to use except you need to provide a valid USERTOKEN.

Comment: I'm really not sure if this ran with you because I'm trying to run it with working data but nothing prints to the console. Even with a URL without headers it's not working!

Comment: The code I posted above works 100% fine. If your apps terminates then you should consider building it in a way where it does not exit right after request is sent.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I ran the app in the app in it worked, I'm not sure why it didn't run in the main file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

func run(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

run("curl", "https://api.github.com/zen")
```

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks for your reply it really helps with the example `curl https://api.github.com/zen`. However, I'm trying to run another command like: `curl -H 'Authorization: token USERTOKEN’ -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPO/contents/PATH` by inserting double quotations and commas between each flag but I failed to done that. Please help me with that. I also would be so appreciative if you explained more on how the func above is working. Thanks

Comment: The method takes as many arguments as you pass. `run("curl", "param1", "param2", "paramn")`. See [variadic parameters](swift variadic parameters).

Comment: The function creates a [Process](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process) to run the command you pass to it.

Comment: Yes but my question is how to pass a header argument?